# Set custom post title to read only by user

Tags: custom-post-types

I need custom post titles on the backend to be Read Only for all users except admin.  This looks like it should be easy, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

For gain result custom post titles read-only for all users except the admin, you can use the `edit_post` capability along with the `admin_init` hook.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'restrict_custom_post_title_editing');

function restrict_custom_post_title_editing() {
    // Check if the current user is not an admin
    if (!current_user_can('administrator')) {
        // Get the post types for which you want to restrict title editing
        $restricted_post_types = array('your_custom_post_type_slug_here');

        // Loop through each restricted post type
        foreach ($restricted_post_types as $post_type) {
            // Remove the capability to edit the post title
            remove_post_type_support($post_type, 'title');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a step in the right direction. However, that completely removes the custom post title for non-admin users. I need all users to be able to see the title, with admin users being the only ones that can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you can add a condition if you want to grant the capability to edit posts users with the specified role can edit posts of the specified custom post type using `add_cap` and `remove_cap` used for removing the capability to edit the post title.

```
// Loop through each restricted post type
    foreach ($restricted_post_types as $post_type) {
        // Check if the current user is not an admin
        if (!current_user_can('administrator')) {
            // Get the specific role you want to allow for editing (e.g., 'editor')
            $allowed_role = get_role('specific_user_role_here');
            // Add the capability to edit the post title
            $allowed_role->add_cap('edit_' . $post_type);

            // Get the specific role you want to restrict (e.g., 'editor')
            $restricted_role = get_role('specific_user_role_here');

           // Remove the capability to edit the post title
           $restricted_role->remove_cap('edit_' . $post_type);

        }
    }
```